# Leadingzeros function in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Do we have any function for leadingzeros.

Answer (score 9):

Use `format-number(12345, "0000000000")`.

This obviously only works for numbers, and can only pad with zeros, but you can pad with any character using the substring like this:

`concat(substring('0000000000',string-length($val)),$val)`

This can be useful when padding with .... or spaces, for example, or if your value isn't numeric.

Comment: Brilliant ;-) I can throw my recursive template in the bin ;-)

Comment: Is this better? concat(substring('0000000000',string-length($val)),$val)

Comment: @pKarelian: Well, I wouldn't say 'better'.. I'd be more inclined to call it 'not wrong'! Hard to believe that's gone 2 years without someone noticing it before. Fixed it.